# Python. How to search by word in a class?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping

I would like to consider the case when the site structure is crooked, there are a lot of identical classes and tags. In these classes, the necessary information is under different indices, where [3], where [6]. Where not at all. Suppose there is: `'Div' class = 'data-123'` Address `' Div 'class = 'data-123'` Information `' Div 'class = 'data-123' Phone - 1234567890` Etc This is the phone I need to get. And in different cards, it is in a random order, or maybe it doesn’t exist at all. That is, it will not find it by xpath because it is different every time, the selector can be identical with some other parameter. Perhaps by the word "telephone" in this class? How to get out of this situation?

Comment: Thanks for the question. Adding more technical detail (and correct syntax) would be highly appreciated. Also, please make this either a technical question about how to write a specific python function (and then please add details of desired input and output). Or make this a technical question about how to scrape specific websites (and then provide an example website).

Comment: https://www.ua-region.com.ua/ru/kved/49.41
here is the site. if you look at its structure, you will see that there are many identical classes in which the data. but these classes are located in different paths. I would like to search for the desired data by keyword in the class. such as phone number or address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get company titles and telephones you can do:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ua-region.com.ua/ru/kved/49.41"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for company in soup.select(".cart-company-lg"):
    title = company.select_one(".cart-company-lg__title").text
    telephones = [t.text for t in company.select('[href^="tel"]')]

    print(title)
    print(*telephones)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
СПЕЦ-Ф-ТРАНС, ООО
+38 (093) 7756...

...and so on.
```

---

EDIT: To get titles/telephones from company page:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ua-region.com.ua/ru/43434454"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

sidebar = soup.select_one(".company-item-sidebar")

name = sidebar.select_one('span:-soup-contains("Юридическое название")')
name = name.find_next(text=True) if name else "N/A"

telephones = sidebar.select_one('span:-soup-contains("Телефоны")')
telephones = (
    [a["href"] for a in telephones.find_next("div").find_all("a")]
    if telephones
    else []
)

# get other items here
# ...

print(name)
print(telephones)
print()
```

Prints:

```
Юридическое название
['tel:+380636540215', 'tel:+380685496792', 'tel:+380952052509']
```

Comment: if you do not enter the company's cards, then there are no problems with collecting data. but if you go to the card, for example this one https://www.ua-region.com.ua/ru/43434454, you can see the very data that you need to get. phone, mail, website, as well as data on the leader in different cards are in a different order. The difficulty lies precisely in this. Thanks